# Could i be still a 'source energy' specimen without having to follow ANY religion or any of it's religious based rules?

Tags: belief

This stroke me many-a-times. I am not ready to accept any religion, nor any rules. I just wanted to be able to differentiate between *right* or *wrong* without any rules (which judges on the body or out of the body {mentally}) or anything what is **worldly** specific that is to be done to be able to *impress* any of gods, demi-gods or even barely humans (I do not adhere principles to any rules which prevents or lowers the scope of goodness). If a certain rule overrides the most obvious fact and leads to wrong - to that I wanted to plain surrender 'wrong'.

Is this strange for me? or even though If I wanted to follow the principles of a hindu, muslim, jain, a Sikh, a Buddhist, monk, etc or whatever that is **worldly describable**  or whatever it mattered, I just wanted to pick up the basic good of every religion and mix it into what might be a principle to live a life and just to stick onto what is betterment universally or the least cosmetically (cosmos theories with scientific alignment). **Is that against Hinduism?**

Basics: If *that* is against any (not just hinduism) system, I am looking forward to follow none because this isn't a set specified documentation. There's something more constructive I am looking for to reference and to find something which triggers myself.

Comment: I'm voting to close this  as off-topic because it does not relate to Hinduism, it is unclear what the poster is asking for and is primarily opinion based. This SE cannot validate or prop up  an individual's personal life choices.

Comment: Very good. There are two aspects to religion. One is the outside rituals and dogmas, But within every religion is there another aspect and that is its essence. Due to the dogmas, one loses interest in the core beliefs. However one should be like the swan which can separate milk from water https://www.quora.com/How-does-a-swan-separate-milk-and-water. In other words, accept all faiths, in their Absolute aspect of Unity, and at the same time do not behave sectarian or ill treat others. It is natural to believe that your God is Supreme, however there is no need to denounce the other person's God.

Answer (score 2):

To me, what you are referring to "basic good in every religion" is spirituality, **not any religion in particular.** For most of so called "religious" people, their revelation is the only revelation, and their prophet is the only prophet. Everything else is absolutely false. Most religious people talk in terms of absolute, while a man of understanding is always relative. The only common ground all the religions come to, is spirituality- be it [Quran](http://www.islamreligion.com/articles/10033/islamic-concept-of-spirituality/), [Bible](http://www.bibleinfo.com/en/topics/spiritual-growth) or Bhagvat Gita.

Spirituality is life in depth, in ultimate depth. You are centered at your very being. But you can go on living on the circumference, moving freely anywhere — still remaining at the center. Your identity is at the center. You know who you are. You get to decide what's wrong and what's right for you.

For eg. one cannot feel good while planning evil for the world. The sensation you have in your body when you are making decision about options you have in your life will let you know if something is good or evil. To murder a person you must manifest ill-will and hatred inside you, and similarly to do something nice to another person, you must be filled with grace and gratefulness inside.

To sum up, being "source energy", spiritual or following "basic good of every religion" has nothing to do with finding any scriptures that are ideal(or mixing up the good things from existing ones to make a new religion), it has something to do with transformation of your own consciousness.

Comment: beautiful answer sir!